# Navigating Daejeon, Korea as an English-speaker

Tags: planning, south-korea, language-barrier, english-language

I am considering a attending a scientific conference in Daejeon, South Korea but I only speak English. I would like some insight on how difficult the city is to navigate for a speaker of English-only.

I am fairly confident I can navigate the conference itself, because I am familiar with the community and the website is in English.

I would also like to know any key travel considerations for going from USA to South Korea, as I have never done so before.

Comment: Note that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daejeon) links to Daejeon's [official website in English](https://www.daejeon.go.kr/english/index.do). I also asked ChatGPT this question, and the answer was sensible, but we don't like quoting that site.

Comment: Not specific to Daejeon, but likely still useful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36797/speaking-korean-without-really-speaking-korean-as-a-tourist-in-south-korea#36798

Comment: @WeatherVane ChatGPT will give you *many* sensible-looking answers. Some are even true!